# Angular error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] in Meanjs

Tags: angularjs, heroku, meanjs

No idea what is happening with my Meanjs based app. In my localhost works fine with no error but when I deploy to Heroku, this error appears the console. I've tried many things but cant figure it out because the info is very few. Cant understand what kind of dependency is causing the problem. It just happened whe I had to show the test to the employer.. very sad with heroku... any other place like heroku to deploy a meanjs app? Thanks!

Link with: [Meanjs app in Heroku](http://fierce-crag-7725.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Were you ever able to identify the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the inline array annotation for dependencies injection?
This is what i mean:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);
```

If you don't, Heroku will minify your scripts, renaming your dependencies' names and let Angular throw the $Injector error.

Comment: Hi @Cluk3, thanks for answer. Thanks for answer. This is how my controller looks: `angular.module('devprofiles').controller('DevprofilesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Devprofiles',
 function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Devprofiles) {`